# Prove that inverse of a linear function is linear

Tags: functions, inverse

I need to prove that the inverse function of a linear function is also linear? I suppose that a linear function is defined like this: $$f(x)=ax+b$$ but how can I prove that its inverse is linear?

Comment: It is supposed to reverse the results of the original function (codomen) back to the original x-es (domen).

Comment: @StefanSmith: Terminology depends on subject area. In calculus, $f(x) = ax+b$ for any value of $a$ and $b$ is a linear function ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function)).

Comment: Sorry, in my language, it's called linear (it's pronounced like that literally), but thanks for the help :D

Comment: @A6Tech: As Stefan mentions, one must have $a\neq 0$. With this, a good first step is finding the inverse of $f(x)$. While that is not always easy (or possible) for functions in general, it is certainly doable in this case. Do you know how?

Comment: @A6Tech : once you've found the formula for the inverse function it will be extremely obvious that it is also a linear function.

Comment: @rghthndsd : I don't consider calculus "higher math", so the way people use the word "linear" in calculus does not contradict what I wrote. But I checked the link you gave me and a link there, and it suggests that people who work with analytic varieties (which I would consider "higher math") might call "$ax+b$" a linear function.   So I can't support my blanket statement, and I deleted my comment.  Thanks for pointing out a probable mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=ax+b\implies x=\frac{y-b}a=\frac1ay-\frac ba$$

In the comments it was already explained why it *has* to be $\;a\neq 0\;$ ...